# How to add column to multiple data frames based on information from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies if this question is simple/been answered elsewhere - I have looked but as a newbie I can't seem to find what I need.

I have a data frame (Length) which contains a a unique value which I need to add to different files

```
View(Length)
        File_name                                                 Transcript_length                                                                 <d
    1 sample15.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv          89229486
    2 sample16.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv          70908644
    3 sample2.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv           56017470
    4 sample28.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv          94888762
    5 sample30.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv         106260465
    6 sample31.fasta.out_alternative.out_contig.copynumber.csv          91189772
```

I have then imported and began to manipulate these copy.number.csv files but need to add a new column which contains the value corresponding to the file name?

Attempt 1:

```
  #import copynumber data
import2 <- list.files(pattern="*copynumber.csv", full.names = TRUE)
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(import2, make.names(gsub("$", "", import))),
         read.csv, sep = ""),
  envir = .GlobalEnv)
CN_files <- lapply(import2, read.csv, sep = "")
names(CN_files) <- gsub("$", "", import2)

#then manipulate 
for (f in 1:length(CN_files)) {

  names(CN_files[[f]]) <- c("Family", "Element", "Length", "Fragments", "Copies", "Solo_LTR", "Total_Bp", "Cover")
```

how do I then add the transcript length values to a new column based on the specific copynumber.csv file provided by the earlier data frame?

Any help greatly appreciated, again, I am new to this, so feel free to give more general advice on how to  word a R question etc

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out how to do it outside of the loop as so:

```
CN_files[[1]] <- CN_files[[1]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[1])
CN_files[[2]] <- (CN_files[[2]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[2]))
CN_files[[3]] <- (CN_files[[3]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[3]))
CN_files[[4]] <- (CN_files[[4]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[4]))  
CN_files[[5]] <- (CN_files[[5]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[5]))
CN_files[[6]] <- (CN_files[[6]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[6]))
CN_files[[7]] <- (CN_files[[7]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[7]))  
CN_files[[8]] <- (CN_files[[8]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[8]))
CN_files[[9]] <- (CN_files[[9]] %>% mutate(bp = Length$Transcript_length[9]))
```

Nevertheless, this seems quite awkward and non-efficient so again if anyone has any tips on how to approach this better it will be greatly appreciated!

- Note, it was known that the order of the files within the list were the same as the 'Length' data file-